# Anyone know why I can’t use kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat instead of kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger for an AudioStreamBasicDescription?

Tags: iphone

Why does this work?

```
- (void)setupAudioFormat:(AudioStreamBasicDescription*)format 
{
    format->mSampleRate = 44100;
    format->mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    format->mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    format->mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    format->mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    format->mBytesPerPacket = 2;
    format->mBitsPerChannel = 32;
    format->mReserved = 0;

    format->mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian |
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
}
```

but when I change the mFormatFlag it doesn't and I get a kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError.

```
format->mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat |
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian |
    kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
```

I am recieving the error when calling...

```
OSStatus    status = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState.dataFormat,
                        AudioInputCallback,
                        self,
                        CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                            kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                        0,
                        &recordState.queue);
```

I am sure the problem lies in the format flags as the error only happens when I try to use the float flag, any ideas how to get around it?

Many thanks.

Comment: You state the constants you change that cause the error, but since you don't actually specify what you are doing it is almost impossible to give you answer that is more than a guess. What function are you calling that actually causes an error for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, but a hard one to answer and has taken many hours, but it looks like floats are not supported.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer might be true for iOS 2.x, but for any recent (64-bit) iOS device, 32-bit floats are actually the native format for Audio Unit samples.